# HTTP 503 error while batch downloading

Tags: bash, http, download, wget, http-error

A complete pdf on a website not is available for the public. Single pages can be downloaded by anyone. Thus I'm downloading it with a bash `for` loop

```
for i in {1..364}
do 
     wget  -O $i.pdf "http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/imgsrv/download/pdf?id=njp.32101015068578;orient=0;size=100;seq=$i;attachment=0"
done
```

Unfortunately, after downloading 16 pages, I start getting

```
ERROR 503: Service Unavailable
```

If I change wget to curl, I get the [following](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11524130/) error message. At first the try-after time is 5 minutes.

A workaround would be to add a 5min sleep every 16 pages. But is there a better workaround?

Comment: Does this command work from bash prompt? `wget -O 1.pdf http://webpage.com/downloadpdf?page=1`? Are you sure, that there are no login requirements?

Comment: Yes, ~15 pages are properly downloaded. And after waiting quite a long time (> 15 min) the pages 16,17,... are downloaded properly as well.

Comment: Try to put sleep when, say, `$i modulo 5 == 0`. Perhaps you are being challanged by a captcha or similar checking.

Comment: doesn't help either. I increased the sleep delay to 5s. The error appears only in wget, even if I added `--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"`. In the browser the link is opened as it should.

Comment: This doesn't help either: http://www.askapache.com/linux/wget-header-trick.html

Comment: Can you manually download pages 18-100 via wget? skip the looping part... Also, instead of `wget`, `curl` can give you more options, like referred page, etc. EDIT: looks like wget is powerful too...

Comment: No, it doesn't work even manally. I previously made the mistake of not quoting the address.

Comment: What happens if you start your counter at 14? Also, is there a redirect on the site you're downloading from? If so you can account for that with a curl option to follow redirects

Comment: Well, the behavior is analogical. Updated the OP content.